# Is there a way to reuse a template for storing data into different identical collections using meteor SimpleSchema + Autoforms?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

---

### **I'm updating the original question a bit since I've found answer to the first section of what I'd been looking for.**

### NEW QUESTION:

As of now, I have a single schema definition that attaches itself to 3 collection namely C1, C2, C3.

```
 some_schema = new SimpleSchema ({
    ...
    });
C1.attachSchema(some_schema);
C2.attachSchema(some_schema);
C3.attachSchema(some_schema);
```

The end goal of what I'm doing is:

If User chose `option B via option A`, then the form must be `stored in C1 Collection`. Similarly, if user chose `option A via option C`, then the form must be `stored in C2 collection`. 
The form that is presented to the user by itself is identical no matter how the user ended to with `option A`.

When it came to the templates, I had to replicate them three times as there can't exist multiple templates with identical names.

My only gripe with the above approach is that if there are 30 instead of 3 templates, then I'll have to end up dealing with maintaining 30x3 = 90 templates with different template names even though they are identical!

Would you happen to know any better means to handle this?

---

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

I was trying to reuse a particular schema definition that I had written. Is it possible to attach the same schema definition to different collection based on a condition?

At the end of it all, I need to store the same type of object in different collection based on what dropdown is selected.

Eg., I have a 3 options to choose from a list-group. 
A
B
C

I have a generic schema defined for X.

depending on the selection made (either A B or C) I will need to attach the schema to collection1 collection2 or collection3.

Basic idea is..

```
some_schema = new SimpleSchema ({
...
});

if ( option A)
then collection1.attachSchema(some_schema);
else if (option B)
then collection2.attachSchema(some_schema);
else if (option C)
then collection3.attachSchema(some_schema);
```

Is this possible? If so, I'd really appreciate some pointers for me to head in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Could you use inheritance/polymorphism to handle this?  Create a base Schema, then extend it to more specific instances.  Then you have one per collection.

Comment: I'm refining my question a bit since I got the answer to the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would these schemas be conditional? Are you using multiple schemas for each of the 3 collections? The purpose of the schema is to validate the structure of inserts and updates. Also a schema isn't really meant to be attached/removed dynamically.  I would recommend just doing:

```
collection1.attachSchema(some_schema);
collection2.attachSchema(some_schema);
collection3.attachSchema(some_schema);
```

And then doing your insert into the appropriate schema based on your option.

Finally, if you have 3 identical schemas, why not just combine them into one and distinguish them with a `type` variable of some kind (essentially the value of your `option` variable.

```
doc.type = option;
collection.insert(doc);
```

Otherwise you're always going to have this awkward collection picker whenever you read or write one of these objects.

Comment: Thanks! At the end of the day, what I actually wanted was if User chose option B via option A, then the form must be stored in X Collection. Similarly, if user chose option A via option C, then the form must be stored in Y collection. The schema as well as the form by themselves need to be identical. I got the schema attached to all three collections the way you've mentioned. However, when it came to the templates, I had to replicate them three times as there can't exist multiple templates with identical names.

Comment: My only gripe with the above is that if there are 30 instead of 3 templates, then I'll have to end up dealing with 30x3 = 90 templates with different template names even though they are identical! Would you happen to know any better means to handle this? I shall also update the original question

Comment: You could just make an array of templates and then index into them. Personally I would keep my data model DRY though. Repeating a schema seems very strange.

Comment: Would you please provide pointers to making an array of templates? Are you referring to [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#combining-simpleschemas) ?